# Gitlab CI pipeline takes too long to build every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, caching, gitlab-ci

I am using docker and Gitlab CI for deploying my app on AWS and I would like to improve my pipeline build time. The problem is that it requires a lot of time to download the libraries everytime I build a new image. Here is my 'before_script' job:

```
before_script:
 - which apk
 - apk add --no-cache curl jq python python-dev python3-dev gcc py-pip docker openrc git libc-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev nodejs yarn make
 - pip install awscli
 - pip install 'docker-compose<=1.23.2'
```

I think that it would be possible by storing the libraries in cache maybe for future reuse, but I can't find the way it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the cache in some cases.

BUT in this scenario I think is better that you build a docker image with all your dependencies built-in. Next, you use that new image (which already has all dependencies) to deploying.

In the Gitlab-CI pipeline, you can set the image at each stage. You would configure the new one.